# php html dom parentheses in href

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

php simple html DOM has some problem with parentheses in href
If you have a `sample.php` page and it contains:

```
<a href="this-href-contains-(parentheses)-and-more-texts"></a>
```

if you do like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('sample.php');
foreach($html->find('a[href*=(parentheses)]') as $element) 
        { 
            echo $element->href;
        }
```

or like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('sample.php');
foreach($html->find('a[href*=this-href]') as $element) 
        { 
            echo $element->href;
        }
```

It works.
But if you write something after or before the parentheses it doesn't work:
This:

```
$html = file_get_html('sample.php');
foreach($html->find('a[href*=contains-(parentheses)]') as $element) 
        { 
            echo $element->href;
        }
```

Or this:

```
$html = file_get_html('sample.php');
foreach($html->find('a[href*=(parentheses)-and-more]') as $element) 
        { 
            echo $element->href;
        }
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Since when do URLs have parentheses?  If it's not HTML compliant, it's a bug in the HTML.

Comment: @Julie Pelletier URLs can have parentheses Some thing like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Oh!  Nice to know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that does not work is because there is a glaring error in the Simple HTML DOM code (well, one of many):

On line 673 of simple_html_dom.php you will see the line:

```php
return preg_match("/".$pattern."/i", $value);
```

Change it to:

```php
return preg_match("/".preg_quote($pattern)."/i", $value);
```

Presto, problem solved.

You can report the error here: https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/bugs/ but with all the errors about the `find` method and others it is likely already reported.